# How do I reload .inputrc?

Tags: bash, unix, readline, inputrc

### Background

I have heard that the [**readline**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) module is reading `~/.inputrc` and that is how it changes the behaviour of keystrokes under programs such as bash.

### Question

How can I reload this after editing to see the changed behaviour without restarting my terminal program?

Comment: Background *(not wrong)*.

Comment: Is there a way to call Readline to reload the history? Like `xmonad ----recompile && xmonad --restart` for reloading XMonad?

Comment: I came here looking for how to load .inputrc with a command. http://superuser.com/q/419670/56544

Comment: Simply restart Bash.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it seems that you have not read the question properly
"How can I reload this after editing to see the changed behaviour _without restarting my terminal program_?"

Comment: @CaptainLepton I saw that. The terminal is not the same as the shell. Doing `exec bash` in a Bash session will replace the current shell session with a new Bash session. `xterm` is a terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the clarification. That is a good idea. Would you perhaps describe running > exec bash as running a new shell in the current terminal rather than restarting bash, as you are replacing your previous executable?

Comment: Yes, there is no way of "restarting" the current shell session. This is *one* way of doing it. Using the solution that @maxelost gave is another.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

By default, `C-x C-r` is bound to `re-read-init-file`.

See the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands) for explanation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried a different mapping in the .inputrc file and also no luck: 

"\eX\eR": re-read-init-file

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Captain Actually, it does, except it does not *clear* keystrokes that were deleted in the meantime. If you e.g. add some, they are loaded. Your only solution for these is a new `bash -l` (shell that behaves like a login shell) that is freshly initialized.

Comment: I was editing `/etc/inputrc` but I had an almost empty `~/.inputrc` that was preventing the one in `/etc/` from being used.  Removing `~/.inputrc` caused it to read `/etc/inputrc` and make my changes active.

Comment: @Malvineous I've been caught out by that before.. if you add `$include /etc/inputrc` to the top of `~/.inputrc`, it avoids this problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: `bash --version` reports `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 running bash in Gnome terminal 3.36.2. I checked `bind -P` and the keystroke is listed but running CTRL-x CTRL-r doesn't reread the file. On the other hand following answer by @studgeek (https://superuser.com/a/1064223/201206) works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 95):

You can also reload new entries from command line using `bind -f ~/.inputrc`. That will load the entries in .inputrc. Note that it just does a load, not a "reload" - so it doesn't reset any lines you happen to have removed from the .inputrc.

To quickly test from a clean slate, just run `bash` then work inside that new nested shell (or start a new terminal).

Comment: I see, correct me if I'm wrong, that `bind -f` only really accepts a filename, and not a file, so something like `bind -f <(echo 'one line with ~/.inputrc syntax')` (or, trivially, `bind -f <(cat ~/.inputrc)`) will not work. This is a bit annoying. Do you know what could I do in this respect?

Comment: You can call first `bind -r` to remove any keyseq.

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me

`bind -f  ~/.inputrc`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153357/inputrc-file-not-sourcing-correctly/246422#246422

Answer (score 13):

In .inputrc first choose your binding and after bind the `re-read-init-file` function:

```
set editing-mode vi
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd>, release both, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: This only works during initialization, i.e. for the editing mode you start the session with. If after this you change the `edtiing-mode` to `emacs`, then you won't get the keybinding. And AFAIK you need to fallback to the `bind -f` method.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```bsh
exec $SHELL
```

This runs the current shell again, without creating a subprocess, and it involves doing all the usual initialisations and script reading, so any new or changed settings in /etc/inputrc, ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc etc. become effective.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet for `~/.inputrc` will map <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-r</kbd> in all keymaps (emacs, vim command mode and vim insert mode):

```
set keymap emacs
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file

set keymap vi-command
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file

set keymap vi-insert
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
```