# How do I reload .inputrc using a bash script?

Tags: bash, readline, inputrc

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/241187) explains how to reload `.inputrc` using `C-x C-r`. But how would one reload it using commands in a bash script?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the `bind` command:

```
bind -f ~/.inputrc
```

See `help bind` for more information:

```
-f  filename       Read key bindings from FILENAME.
```

Comment: This doesn't unbind removed entries.

Comment: I am a bit surprised to see that the `-f` option accepts only a **filename**, not a file, which means, for instance, that `bind -f <(cat ~/.inputrc)` has no effect. I run into this while trying to pass a single `set` line to `bind -f`.