# Enabling readline?

Tags: linux, bash, readline

I have an `.inputrc` file set up on a system that doesn't seem to be respecting it.  If I `bind` the file (as per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/419670/how-do-i-reload-inputrc-using-a-bash-script)) or [try to load it with `C-x C-r`](https://superuser.com/questions/241187/how-do-i-reload-inputrc), nothing happens - I still do not get any of the readline functions I'm looking for, especially `history-search-backward`.

Is it possible I'm using a bash shell without readline enabled?  If so, how do I determine that definitively?  If not, is there something else I need to do to enable readline?  The system in question is SUSE Linux version 3.16.7-21-desktop

EDIT with additional information:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

`.inputrc` (including my comments).  I'm using this same `.inputrc` on many other machines, so I don't expect it is the problem:

```
# "\e[A" and "\e[B" being whatever your terminal uses for up & down.
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward

# Two escapes clear command line.
"\e\e": "\C-a\C-k"

# do history expansion when space entered
# Space: magic-space

#set editing-mode vi
$include /etc/inputrc
```

Comment: Is `INPUTRC` variable set?

Comment: Yes, `INPUTRC` is set, and it is set to the correct file (the expanded version of `~/.inputrc`)

Comment: Can you post your `~/.inputrc`?

Comment: Also, what are `$SHELL` and `bash --version`?  Just after you log in, does `ps` show bash?  (The shell version of "is it plugged in?" :) )

Comment: cxw, Arkadiusz Drabczyk: see edits.  "is it plugged in" is always a good question, and I'm not always sure how best to ask it - thanks.