# Enable alt/ctrl + left/right on CentOS command line

Tags: linux, inputrc

My hoster recently updated to a new CentOS and I've been 'personalizing' it and now I'm missing something.

On my home Ubuntu Server I can `forward-word` and `backward-word` with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> / <kbd>LEFT</kbd>. I didn't do anything for that. I can also <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> to delete a word.

On my new CentOS I can do the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, but I can't get the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> / <kbd>LEFT</kbd> working! <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> / <kbd>F</kbd> work, but that's just not acceptable, because it only works for the left <kbd>ALT</kbd> and my fingers aren't that lean. (right <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> / <kbd>F</kbd> just prints "b" or "f")

I've tried copying a part of /etc/inputrc to CentOS, but that doesn't do anything.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, I don't care, but I really need a shortcut. The last CentOS didn't have it, but since Ubuntu I've been missing it on CentOS.

My CentOS `/etc/inputrc`:

```
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
```

My Ubuntu `/etc/inputrc`:

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

I don't even know what they all mean!? What is `[1;5C` for key??

Comment: I just use the first 2 lines (`\e[1;5C` and `\e[1;5D`) you quote from your Ubuntu inputrc in my `~/.inputrc` and it works fine for debian, ubuntu and arch.

Comment: For `ALT` or `CTRL`? Since those are in there, they should work, wouldn't you think? Two of them must be `B` and `F`, I would think. Linux is weird.

Comment: They work for `CTRL`. My _guess_ is that order is important, one may overwrite the other. Also, local settings files (e.g. `~/.inputrc`) take precedence over system-wide ones, so if there is a weird conflict somewhere a local file might fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to your question I finally did some reading and increased my understanding, cheers!

So, a very good source of information is `man readline`. The keybindings specified in the various `inputrc` files control the way that the BASH readline library works. According to the readline manpage you can use either symbolic key names or escape sequences:

```
   Key Bindings
       The syntax for controlling key bindings in the inputrc file is
       simple.  All that is required is the name of  the  command  or
       the  text  of a macro and a key sequence to which it should be
       bound. The name may be specified in one of two ways: as a sym‐
       bolic  key  name, possibly with Meta- or Control- prefixes, or
       as a key sequence.  The name and key sequence are separated by
       a  colon.  There can be no whitespace between the name and the
       colon.

       When using the form keyname:function-name or macro, keyname is
       the name of a key spelled out in English.  For example:

              Control-u: universal-argument
              Meta-Rubout: backward-kill-word
              Control-o: "> output"
```

The man page also states that the default configuration file is `~/.inputrc` so I recommend placing your bindings there.

If you want to use normal letter keys (for example <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>), `Control-g: forward-word` works fine. The arrow keys are harder. I tried, and failed, to find the key **name** for the arrow keys. None of the ones I tried (`left-arrow`, `left`, `:left`) worked so it seems like we are stuck with the escape sequences.

Unfortunately, the exact escape sequence differs between terminal emulators (that is why your Ubuntu inputrc had multiple lines). To find out which escape sequence your favorite terminal uses, run `read` and then type the key sequence you are interested in. In `terminator`, `xterm` and `gnome-terminal`, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> give:

```
$ read
^[[1;5D
```

in `aterm`:

```
$ read
^[Od    <-- that is a capital O not a zero (0).
```

By experimenting a bit, I figured out that `^[[D` is <kbd>Left</kbd> and `^[[1;5D` is <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>. The first `^[` is the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, used here, I suppose, to denote an **escape sequence**.

In any case, to bind <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> to `forward-word` in a way that works for all, I added these lines to my `~/inputrc`:

```
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
```

For reasons I have not fully understood, <kbd>Control</kbd> is represented by `\e` which *should* be <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

My final `~/.inputrc` file that works for all the terminals listed above is:

```
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\eOc": forward-word
```

Comment: YES YES YES! You are my absolute hero! It's perfect now! My tiny air keyboard now uses right ctrl + arrows and my main/desktop keyboard now uses left alt + arrow keys. Perfect!! Somehow my air keyboard's right alt doesn't trigger anything in `read`... Probably the keyboard's fault (some special function!?). Awesome! You the man!

Comment: My settings are a bit different btw: ctrl left / right: `\eOD` / `\eOC` and alt left / right: `\e\e[D` / `\e\e[C`. Thank god it's a readable, sensible syntax like this, right!? Linux rocks!

Comment: Yeah, got to admit the syntax could be better, probably a historical relic. Glad it works!

Answer (score 1):

**How to do it in Iterm2 so that it works when you connect to any host.**

*Note: I only write this because, another question (https://superuser.com/questions/1042937/getting-ctrlarrows-to-move-word-at-a-time-on-newest-iterm2?rq=1) has linked to this question as a duplicate, but this question does not answer how to do this in Iterm2, so it isn’t really a duplicate.*

If you are on OS X and using Iterm2 you can map <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→ (right arrow)</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to the standard readline commands <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. In the example below it is assumed that the escape key is meta. To do this, open Iterm2.

1. Click: Menu -> Preferences...
2. Click “Profiles” tab.
3. Click your profile or the default one.
4. Click the “Keys” sub tab.
5. Click the “+” plus sign next to “Load Preset…”
6. Type your keyboard shortcut in the first field (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>)
7. Choose either “Send Text”, “Send Hex” (more on sending Hex in “How to bind a key sequence to the control key” below) or “Send Escape Sequence”. In this case we are using "Send Escape Sequence”.
8. In the last field choose characters that readline can interpret.
9. `^[` is the readline sequence for escape. This entry maps <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (may be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in other terminals)

[image: key mapping window example]

**How to map shortcuts to non-escape sequences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, etc.)**

1. Download “Key Codes” from the app store. Install it and open it.
2. While in an open Key Codes window, hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*[some key]*</kbd>, in this case I’ll use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for deleting a previous word in readline.
3. Note the “Unicode” field.
4. Now map your key sequence using in iterm, preferences->Keys->+ (the sequence provided above).
5. Enter “Keyboard Shortcut” field something like in this situation <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
6. Change “Action” to “Send Hex Code”.
7. Enter in last field the previously noted hex; in this case, `23` / `0x17`.
8. Click “OK" and the shortcut should now be operational in your terminal window and work on any system where readline is available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. Had this problem with PuTTY on CentOS 7 and solved by adding this inside the `$if mode=emacs` conditional:

```
# for PuTTY
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

[Activated the setting](https://superuser.com/a/241190/288643) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>